# MySQL Workbench won't allow me to select Varbinary data type

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, varbinary

I am trying to set-up some encryption of tables in MySQL Workbench.Encrypt data is necessary to store it as Var binary, however when I try to select this data type my workbench gives me an error message (shown in the image below) and reverts to a previous data type. Any help with overcoming this is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: When you select this type, specify a size (`Varbinary(10)` for example) or remove the `()` from the Datatype column so it will get the default size

Comment: Why don't you post this comment as answer? It's the only thing that can be said for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Provide specific size within (). Otherwise remove () to set it to the default size.
ex: VARBINARY(5)